# I want to fetch data from Unsplash API with Axios in Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch

I am not sure how to write the params down.

First component:

```
import unsplash from '../apis/unsplash.vue';

export default {
created() {
    unsplash.get('https://api.unsplash.com/GET/photos/random').then((response)=>{
    params:{
        count:10
    }
    })
console.log(response.data)
}};
</script>
```

Second component:

```
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const API_KEY=`oozTUUGcoOmOleTWzWgrDTU04NmhO8a-pxF5TmPPNKw`

export default axios.create({
baseURL:'https://api.unsplash.com',
params:  {
        API_KEY:API_KEY,
        per_page:10,
        type:"image"}});
</script>
```

Comment: import unsplash from '../apis/unsplash.vue';

export default {
created() {
    unsplash.get('https://api.unsplash.com/GET/photos/random').then((response)=>{
    params:{
        count:10
    }
    })
 console.log(response.data)
}};
</script>

Comment: Format your code and ask a clear question.

Comment: You should probably now change your API key when you publish it here...